# How to refresh page when it is changed

Tags: html, angular

Is there a way to refresh page in Angular project if some elements were added to it?
For example, I have this:

```
<form class="">
<div class="form-group col-md-offset-4">
    <label>Firstname</label>
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Firstname" style="width:40%" name="username" [(ngModel)]="user.name" required />
</div>
</form>
```

If I add another `div` during the runtime and reload that page, no changes would be made. Even after I restart that project, changes won't appear. The only way to see them is to clear browsing data. What am I missing here?

Comment: How do you add the `<div>`? I don't understand "If I add another div during the runtime and reload that page, no changes would be made." Do you expect changes to persist after a reload?

Comment: In visual studio I add new div element to the form in my .html file and save changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you running your project in a live server like for example using the ng serve command included in angular-cli?

If so, check that the live-reload option is enabled (-lr)

To avoid problems with browsers' cache, open it in development mode. Some browsers like Firefox have a special option that you have to check to prevent the browser from caching your javascript code.